# Mysql Server installed with homebrew always gone

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

im using Bic Sur with M1 Chip and running mysql installed with homebrew.

For installation it's run well, and mysql also run well but only for some time.

after restart the engine, i always lost my sql server especially my information_schema database, and  i don't know what's made it happened.

[image: After view days of installation]
[image: Even it succeed to start]

Comment: Try to remove it and then reinstall. And by the way the command to start with brew is ‘ brew services start mysql’

Comment: Hi @Canh , In my case the command is right (no problem of running it).. actually ive tried to reinstall over and over... but i've figured out whats triggered my case...actually what's trigger my case is some db ive export from ubuntu (i was migrated from ubuntu to mac) and i suspected phpadmin db of ubuntu triggered somethin in mac phpmyadmin so its turn to error..so i tried to export my db 1 after another and no problem till today..thanks for replying